# greping with os command assigning it in tupe want to remove /t

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
args = parser.parse_args()
find = args.data_variable

cmd = commands.getoutput("cat /cc/ddd '"+find+"' |grep -A 3 node | tail -n +2")

r = tuple(cldb.split('\n'))
print r
```

i get the out put in tuples but it has /t please help how to remove it.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: ('\t\tm\mrcg1234', '\t\tmrcg1235', '\t\tmrcg1235.me.com')

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.strip()`

**Ex:**

```
cldb = ('\t\tm\mrcg1234', '\t\tmrcg1235', '\t\tmrcg1235.me.com')
cldb = tuple([i.strip() for i in cldb])
print(cldb)
```

**Output:**

```
('m\\mrcg1234', 'mrcg1235', 'mrcg1235.me.com')
```

Comment: cmd = commands.getoutput("cat /cc/ddd '"+find+"' |grep -A 3 node | tail -n +2")
cmd is of type string how to assign the getoutput command out put to tuple?

Comment: What does cmd print ? What is your expected output?

Comment: cmd prints three lines with the tab  
                mrcg1234
  mrcg1235
  mrcg1235
I want to make it as tuple without  tab